# Tensorflow not being consistent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building an optimizer for Keras in tensorflow v1 in Python. The optimizer works by running "get_updates" one time to get a list of updates to execute each iteration in the training. The complete code is rather long, but the following should be enough to understand what's happening:

```
def get_updates(self, params):
   self.saved_params = K.zeros((self.d,1), name='X_previous')

    P = tf.cond( self.repeat, lambda: self.saved_params, lambda: self.flattenParams(params))
    self.updates.append(tf.print("P,params,repeat:",P, self.flattenParams(params), self.repeat ))

    self.updates.append(K.update( self.saved_params, P))
    return self.updates
```

The "repeat" variable is changed in the code too, but it depends on some counters and stuff which appears to work correctly. The strange thing is that when I run this code I get the following output:

```
P,params,repeat: 0, 4034.73706, 0
```

Which makes absolutely no sense. If **repeat** is 0 then **P** should be the same as **params**. The even stranger part is that sometimes it is the same, sometimes it's 0. I've tried adding *with tf.control_dependencies([self.repeat, self.saved_params, P]):* but nothing changed. I've tried adding control dependencies pretty much everywhere I can, no difference. Still this random behaviour. It's also worth noting that the initial value of **self.repeat** is *False*, so by default **P** should be the same as **params**, yet the very first iteration **P** is somehow 0. What's going on here?

Comment: You need to provide a _complete_ example, else it's impossible to say anything. There can be many things wrong here, my guess would be that you are misunderstanding the way TF 1.x does its computations (build graph once, execute repeatedly) and this messes up the condition; I also wonder why you are (from what I can see) mixing TF and Keras code which is generally a bad idae.

Comment: I'll try to see if I can recreate the error in a smaller piece of code, right now it's several files so it would be a lot of code to just post here. I'm using the code for Keras optimizers as a reference, they used K.update hence I'm also using it. I don't think Keras has a build in "condition", so I have to use tf.cond

Answer (score 0):

It appears I had just messed up the order I added my updates in the list (whoopsie), so stuff was updated in a strange order. I'm still not sure why it wasn't consistently wrong, but I'm guessing Tensorflow didn't see a connection between the updates and thought it could do them at the same time. I added some control dependencies and made sure to update everything in a more sensible order (I had just put the updates at the end of the function, not thinking that much about the order because in my previous optimizers the order did not matter).
I still have some strange things when I print, my index counter is printing odd but I'm pretty sure that's just the print function acting up since everything else is working fine.